# Can't redirect URL on Google Chrome browser

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, post, browser

I want to redirect after payment, My page have check some **post data**[payment status] and **sessions** for redirect to other page in same site.

In other browser search as **Safari**(mobile), *Firefox* and **MS Edge**, It's works fine. But In **Google Chrome** can't load page in **header('')**

This my code

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['PAYMENT_PRODUCTTYPE'] == "TA")
{
    if($_POST['payment_status'] == '000' )
    { 
        header('Location: /travel_insurance/thankyou');
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

**[Update]**

It's my workflow
[image]

I search many way to resolve this problem, I'm not sure. It's maybe because **browser updates**.
I try to add `Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=None` in the application vhost but not works for me.

pls help me to resolve it, or maybe give me some reason for this :)

Comment: Is there any redirection to another site for payment process?

Comment: @Crezzur - Why are you linking to a question without any accepted or even upvoted answer? As far as I can tell, that question went unanswered.

Comment: @Crezzur - Which answer? And what does that answer have that the OP is missing? If I test the posted code here, it actually works as expected in all browsers.

Comment: When you test this in Chrome, what happens? Have you checked if it's any of the if-statements that doesn't evaluate as true and that all variables contains what you expect? As far as I can tell, there's nothing in the posted code that would make it behave differently in different browsers.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I think it is because of same-site cookies! any idea about it?

Comment: @ArashShiri - What does cookies have to do with redirects? Or are you referring to the session cookie? I'm assuming (might be a mistake though) that this code is on the same site as the rest of their code (like where they set the session data) so I'm not sure how that would be an issue in that case. We don't know enough though. The OP needs to do some more debugging to see where in that code it fails.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - Yes as you said there is no enough info, by according to same-site cookies issue I meant session cookies but again as you said there is no enough info... by the way TNX

Answer (score 0):

Use `ob_start();` in top of the script brfotr `session_start();`

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
if($_SESSION['PAYMENT_PRODUCTTYPE'] == "TA")
{
    if($_POST['payment_status'] == '000' )
    { 
        header('Location: /travel_insurance/thankyou');
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why would they need to do that and how would starting output buffering in PHP make redirects behave differently in different browsers?